# Leaflet bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: leaflet, error

I'm getting the following error in Internet Explorer: " Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' "

The method 'includes' works fine in Chrome and Firefox but throws an error for each instance in IE.

This is an example of the code that is creating the error:

```
            var carmen56= new L.GeoJSON(null, {
            style: function (feature) {


                if (feature.properties.description.includes("Exclude")) {
                    return {
                        clickable: true,
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: .80,
                        fillOpacity:  .55,
                        fillColor: '#55ff00',
                        color: '#000000'
                    };
                }; 
                if (feature.properties.description.includes("Include")) {
                    return {
                        clickable: true,
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: .80,
                        fillOpacity:  .55,
                        fillColor: '#ffaa00', <!--Orange-->
                        color: '#000000'
                    };
                }; 

                if (feature.properties.description.includes("Tier 3")) {
                    return {
                        clickable: true,
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: .80,
                        fillOpacity:  .55,
                        fillColor: '#ff0000',
                        color: '#ff0000'
                    };
                };
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221341/ie-does-not-support-includes-method

Answer (score 1):

If includes doesn't work try something like this:

```
    // Set function for color ramp
    function getColor(league){
    return league == 'NL' ? 'blue' :
           league == 'AL' ? 'red' :
           'white';
           }

///////////////////////////////////

return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
    radius:6,
    opacity: .5,
    color:getColor(feature.properties.League),
    fillColor:  getColor(feature.properties.League),
    fillOpacity: 0.8
```

My example uses a getColor function that reads values from the League field in my GeoJSON file, and if the value is 'NL' returns 'blue', 'AL' returns 'red' and 'white' if it's something else. It avoids the includes function that IE is having a problem with.